# Binomial task data: proper statistical test to use for comparing treatment to control groups?

Tags: regression, binomial-distribution, group-differences

I have fairly simple task data that involves either correct/incorrect responses (binomial?). In the control data, there are 50 trials per subject, in condition 1 there are 50 trials per subject, and in condition 2 there are 50 trials per subject. What I want to do is see if condition 1 is statistically significant when compared to the control data, and then do the same for condition 2. After that, I want to add the overall responses from condition 1 and 2 and compare that to the control data to see if they are statistically significant when combined.

This is a simplified example of the data that I want to find significance with
[image]

What kind of statistical test should I use to test for significance within each subject?

Comment: Is Subject 1 for Control the same subject as Subject 1 for Condition 1?